# angular import path in stackblitz

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I have some issues with importing components/services in stackblitz. Please look at the files `sidebar.component.ts`, `layout.component.ts` and `layout.module.ts`. I tried many forms, no success.

Here is the stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pksnff?file=src/app/components/layout/layout.module.ts

EDIT: it turnet out, that all was fine, I had to restart the stackblitz ide.

Comment: this drives me nuts every time ^^'